# How I can show downloaded images to idex file?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

Here's the code of flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from pygoogle_image import image as pi
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
 image_urls=[]
 if request.method == "POST":
  username = request.form['username']
  phone = request.form['phone']
  prompts = request.form['prompt']
  print(prompts)
  try:
   image_relative_paths = pi.download(keywords=prompts, limit=4)
   print(image_relative_paths)
   if image_relative_paths is not None:
    image_folder = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'images')  # Path to the image folder
    image_urls = [f"/images/{prompts}{image_rel_paths}" for image_rel_paths in       image_relative_paths ]
    print(image_urls)
  except Exception as e:
   return f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
  print("Image URLs:", image_urls)
return render_template('index.html',image_urls=image_urls)
if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to show downloaded images to my index file. I used pygoogle_image library to download images from google based on the keyword that user gave from my index file. I tried to show images but noting happend. Help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

`image_urls = [f"/images/{image_rel_paths}" for image_rel_paths in image_relative_paths]`

Comment: I tried but in terminal my image_relative_path is showing None.